# Is it possible to install the SF Mono font, standard in Apple's Xcode app, on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, installer, truetype-fonts, installation-package

Is it possible to install the SF Mono font, which I understand is standard in Apple's Xcode app, on a Windows machine? (Windows 10 in my case). It is a very pretty font, and it looks to me like it solves more of the programming font problems than any other font that I have used.

In particular, it not only addresses the usual programming font issues -- readable in smaller sizes, horizontally compact, distinguishing capital Os from zeros, 1-I-l, and so forth, it also does a better job of allowing easy discrimination of case. Many programming fonts sacrifice  a good bit of ease of case distinction in the course of achieving legibility at smaller size. This is of particular importance to me as I do most of my programming work in R, or less often C++, both of which case sensitive.

All the distributions of the font I have found are in the form of Apple installation files (.pkg), which I do not know how to use on a Windows machine. Is it possible to install the font on a windows machine without overkill solutions like iOS emulation? If so, how does one go about it? Alternatively, is there a good look-alike font, that achieves the same compactness and coding-related improvements over Helvetica Neue, while being available as a .ttf or some other more-accessible format?

Comment: There is already a thread on this on the internet... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71470/how-to-use-san-francisco-font-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Sure. There's a github repo with all the font files in .otf format. Perfectly compatible with Windows.

https://github.com/ZulwiyozaPutra/SF-Mono-Font

Comment: Actually, this font file looks a bit different to images I've seen around the net, but it's quite close, I believe.